# Do the spectra of compound materials combine linearly with respect to the ratios of the constituent compound spectra?

Tags: spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

My question stems from reading this [article](https://www.machinerylubrication.com/Read/30205/ftir-oil-analysis) on the FTIR spectrum of oil that has been mixed with various contaminants.

If one has the spectrum for the original uncontaminated oil and the spectrum for water, will the spectrum of a sample that has been contaminated with 10% water (by weight) be equivalent to the addition of original oil sample spectrum and 0.1 of the water spectrum intensities?

(Also, should the unit of contamination be the weight or the volume?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right. If you have $n$ components in a mixture each with a spectrum $S_1$, $S_2$,...,$S_n$, the observed spectrum $S_{obsvd}$ would be the sum of $S_1$+ $S_2$+...+$S_n$.

In FTIR you either measure the transmittance or the absorbance. The term intensity is more or less used when you deal with molecular or atomic emission of light (fluorescence etc.) As long as there is no chemical reaction among the constituents, the absorbance should be linear with the concentration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you point me towards any documentation to support this?

Comment: The summation part or the theory of FTIR?

Comment: Search, Beer's law is additive. These are paid but highly reliable services 1. "In defence of Beer's law" https://www.osapublishing.org/josa/abstract.cfm?uri=josa-38-10-854 2. Beer's law and its use in analysis. A review https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1963/an/an9638800678/unauth#!divAbstract

Comment: More specific to Beer's law in the field of FT-IR spectrometry is the 1998 sequel «Extending the Range of Beer's Law in FT-IR Spectrometry.» with part I https://www.osapublishing.org/as/abstract.cfm?uri=as-52-11-1403 and part II https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1366/0003702981943031.  Both sources accessible by subscription.

Comment: Provided intermolecular interaction foes not cause shift in the transition frequencies. Strongly interacting molecules (hydrogen bonding)  show such effects.  in these cases,  the observed spectra can be different ( although small)